# Visual Studio custom build tool?

Tags: visual-studio

I am in need of a tool that will allow me to create a local build definition so that I may select projects in my solution to build in a particular order. It seems that either my configuration of VS 2019 just won't allow me to do that or I'm an idiot on how to do it.

BTW, NOT Visual Studio Code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to achieve this would be to create references between the projects, such that they're built in dependency order.

If you don't actually want to reference the output of the referenced project, you can exclude it via something like:

```xml
<ProjectReference
  Include="..\MyProject\MyProject.csproj"
  ReferenceOutputAssembly="false" />
```